# Ansible: vmware_guest: VM Deployment

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm currently trying to figure out how best to approach a situation where a vCenter has one or more Datacenters with the same name but in different Folder Locations.  Because of this I'm unable to deploy to the correct Cluster: Currently Ansible picks up the first Datacenter it sees and returns an Error if the Cluster isn't part of that particular DataCenter.

> cluster < Name > not found in DC

**Code**

```
  vmware_guest:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: no
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
    cluster: "{{ cluster }}"
    name: "{{ vm_name }}"
    template: "{{ template }}"
    networks:
    - name: "{{ network }}"
      ip: "{{ ip }}"
      netmask: "{{ net_mask }}"
      gateway: "{{ gateway }}"
      domain: my_domain
      dns_servers:

      type: dhcp
```

Comment: Try to give full path with the  name of datacenter

Comment: When you say give the full path, is this on the Datacenter parameter or the folder parameter ?

Comment: Its for `folder` parameter

Comment: I tried the Folder parameter in the past, and was getting: fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! =>  Search path, It stills pionts the full path for the Second Folder;